# c# onchange event only reload data when timer runs. why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, android-viewpager, onchange

I have update panel with a timer. panel contains repeater which has some records. I also use PagedDataSource to paginate repeater's data. I added server method to onchange event which reloads repeater's page size. This event is fired when needed but data reloads only when timer tick executes. therefore, when i change page size, sometimes i need to wait entire timer interval to see page size changed. could anyone explain why this happens? any help would be appreciated

here's some of my code

```
<form id="linksForm" runat="server">
    <div>

        <div style="float: left; background-color: white">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Button ID="DisplayAllLinksBT" OnClick="DisplayAllLinks" runat="server" Text="Visi"/>
        <asp:Button ID="DisplayNewLinksBT" OnClick="DisplayNewLinks" runat="server" Text="Nauji" />
        <asp:Timer ID="TimerLinks" runat="server" Interval="10000" OnTick="OnLinksRepeaterTick">
        </asp:Timer>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="LinksPanel" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

        <div id="loadingImageArea"></div>

        <table style="border: none;">

        <% if (!HasPermission) 
        { %>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <td style="color: green;">Upvotes</td>
                    <td style="color: red;">Downvotes</td>
                </th>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
        <asp:Repeater ID="LinksRepeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
            ...
            <asp:Label ID="PageSizeLabel" runat="server" Text="Rodyti"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="PageSizeSelection" Width="60" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="PageSizeSelection_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```

server side:

```
protected void PageSizeSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pageSize = Int32.Parse(PageSizeSelection.SelectedValue);
    SessionHelper.PutValue(PageSizeSessionVariable, pageSize);

    var lastPageIndex = Math.Ceiling(
        ((float) ((PagedDataSource) LinksRepeater.DataSource).DataSourceCount)/
        (int)pageSize) - 1;

    var currentPageIndex = ((PagedDataSource) LinksRepeater.DataSource).CurrentPageIndex;

    if (lastPageIndex > 0 && currentPageIndex > lastPageIndex)
    {
        SessionHelper.PutValue(CurrentPageIndexSessionVariable, (int)lastPageIndex);
    }

    LoadLinks();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting `autopostback="true"` for the dropdown list.